# Ajax not working when get data based on input for D3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, d3.js

i am working in D3..based on the input i want to fetch data from the database to D3..when i type some word in the input field and click submit it works fine...there is no problem in D3...but when i change the input field there is no action in the submit button..it want me to refresh to search for the new word...is anything wrong in the way i use the ajax here..

```
            $(function (all) {
             $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
               var t=$('form').serialize();
              var u='http://localhost:8888/saff/indexi.php?'+t;
             $.ajax({
             url:u,
            async:true,
            success:function(data){
            funn();
            }
            });
      function funn(){
   d3.json(u, function(treeData) {
          //d3 code
               });
         }
        });
        });
```

secondly,when i change the form input as

```
     <form name="editorForm" id="formi"> 
     <input type="text" name="editor" 
     id="editor" onchange="document.getElementById('formi').submit();"/>
    <input type="submit"value="butn">
    <br />
    </form>
```

type word in the field and submit only making changes in the url as
http://localhost:8888/saff/keyy.html     to   [http://localhost:8888/saff/keyy.html?editor=அகடம்](http://localhost:8888/saff/keyy.html?editor=%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D) and nothing displayed in the webpage
how should i use ajax in d3 to get the data from php to d3 based on input,without page refresh

THE Problem is 
*WHEN THE SUBMIT FIRST WORD IT GET CORRECT DESIGN IN WEBPAGE
*WHEN I CHANGE THE INPUT TEXT,THE SECOND DESIGN COMES BELOW THE FIRST DESIGN
why ajax is not working??? 
UPDATE
my complete code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
              content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Tring Reset</title>
            <style>
            .node {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .overlay {
                background-color:white;
            }
            .node circle {
                fill: #fff;
                stroke: steelblue;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
            .node text {
                 font: sans-serif;

                text-align: center;
            }
            .link {
                fill: none;   
            } 
            .parent{
            fill :red;
            font-weight:lighter;
            }
            div#tooltip {   
                position: absolute;         
                  font: 15px sans-serif;        
                background: orange; 
                 border-radius: 8px;    
                    padding-left: 5px;
                    padding-right: 5px;
                pointer-events: none;           
            }
            </style>
            <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>  
            <form name="editorForm"> 
                    <input type="text"name="editor"/>
            <input type="submit"value="butn">
            </form>
             <div id="tooltip" style="display:none"></div>
            <div id="tree-container"class="full"></div>
            <script>
            $('form').find(':submit').on('click', function() {
                    var t = $('form').serialize();
                    var u = 'http://localhost:8888/saff/indexi.php?' + t;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: u,
                                async: true,
                                success: function(data) {
                                    funn(data);
                                }
                            });
            function funn(){
            var selectedNode = null;
            var draggingNode = null;

            var panSpeed = 200;
            var panBoundary = 0; 

            var i = 0;
            var duration = 750;
            var root;

            var width = $(document).width();
            var height = $(document).height();

            var diameter = 750;

            var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])

                .separation(function (a, b) {
                return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth;
            });
            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
             .projection(function (d) {
                return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
            });
            d3.json(u, function(error, treeData) {
              if (error) throw error;
            root = treeData;
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;
            root = treeData;
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

            function sortTree() {
                tree.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
                });
            }
            sortTree();
            var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1200)
                .attr("height",1200)
                .attr("class", "overlay")

             .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1000 + "," + 1000 + ")");
            function collapse(d) {

                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                }

            update(d);
            }

            function expand(d) {

                if (d._children) {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d.children.forEach(expand);
                    d._children = null;
                }
            }
            function toggleChildren(d) {

                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else if (d._children) {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                return d;
            }

            function click(d) {
            if(!d.parent){
            return;
            }

            if (!d.children) 
                treeData.children.forEach(collapse);

                if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; 

                d = toggleChildren(d);

                update(d);
            }
            function update(source) {
               var levelWidth = [1];
                var childCount = function (level, n) {
                    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
            if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

                        levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
                        n.children.forEach(function (d) {
                            childCount(level + 1, d);
                        });
                    }
                };
                childCount(0, root);
                 var nodes = tree.nodes(root); 
                links = tree.links(nodes);
                node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });
                  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")

                    .attr("class", "node")

                .on('click', click)

                  nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "smallcircle")
                        .style("stroke", function(d) {
                  return d.color;
                })


                nodeEnter.append("text")

                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                })

                    .style("opacity", 1)
                    .style("fill-opacity", 0)

            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            var r = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect();
                       d3.select("div#tooltip")
                            .style("display", "inline")
                           .style("top", (r.top-25) + "px")
                           .style("top", 10 + "px")
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px") 
                          .style("left", r.left + 40+"px")
                          .style("left",  + "px")
                            .style("position", "absolute")
                           .text(d.t);
                     })
                .on("mouseout", function(){
                   d3.select("div#tooltip").style("display", "none")
               })


                node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
                    .attr("r", 4.5)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "red" : "#fff";
                });
             var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
       return "rotate("+(d.x - 90)+")
          translate("+ d.y +")rotate(" + (-d.x + 90) + ")";
                });

                nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 4.5)

                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

                nodeUpdate.select("text")

                   .style("fill-opacity", 9)
               .attr("fill",function(d){return (d.children?"red":"black");})
         .attr("font-size",function(d){return (d.children?"20px":"12px");})
             .attr("dy", ".35em")

                    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                    return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
                })


                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(360)translate(-8)";
                });

                var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
                })
                    .remove();

                nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 0);

                nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 0);


                var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function (d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                })
            link.style("stroke", function(d) {
                  return d.color;
                })

                link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                     link.style("stroke", function(d) {
                  return d.target.color;
                })
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                  });


                link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);


                link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                      var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                  })

                    .remove();
             nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                });
            }
            var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 550 + "," + 300 + ")")
       d3.selectAll("text").style("fill", function (d) 
         { return d3.select(this).classed(d.cond, true); })
            root.children.forEach(function (child) {
                collapse(child);
            });
            update(root);
            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", width);
            });
            }
            return false;
            });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

finally there is no path error in the console but on input change the d3 design shows below the first input design 
any idea?why ajax is not working here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').find(':submit').on('click', function() {
    var t = $('form').serialize();
    var u = 'http://localhost:8888/saff/indexi.php?' + t;
    $.ajax({
        url: u,
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            funn(data);
        }
    });

    function funn(treeData) {
        d3.json(u, function(error, treeData) {
            //d3 code
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thank you sir,for your response and interest here...but sorry to say that still the problem is not clear ..plz see my console pictures in the question..there is some change in the console..but not in the webpage

Comment: does the file in your path actually contain an "i" `indexi.php`?

Comment: I think you have an error somewhere else not in the code given on this page.. According to your screenshots its coming from the d3.js script.. Or the data coming back from the server is not properly formatted json.

Comment: i have one doubt ...then how it works when i refresh the page for every input field change,if there is any problem in the d3 and php?

Comment: you want it to submit on each character on keyup?

Comment: actually ,when i type the complete word fruit and click submit ,it should show the related d3 design in the webpage

Comment: thanks for your update sir,my bad day ,i cant able to come out from this problem ...i used your work in my code...plz see my update

Comment: sir,same console as i posted in the question

Comment: seems you have an old version of jquery as well that is spitting out errors with "getPreventDefault" being deprecated. Update to at least jquery version 1.11 and try again..

Comment: finally,input change shows the design below the first word design..final code in the update